# textfield label is not aligning correctly

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have some issues with aligning things in the text field in flutter. take a look at the snapshot below
[image]

issue #1 - look at the label in the first text field (Income Amount).  It is not centered with the Icon on the left.  how do I make the label text in the text field centered with the prefix icon? in the picture below, the label text appeared a little bit off the center of the icon.

issue #2 - take a look at the dropdown Frequency.  When I choose a value, the floating label moves to the top but leaves a huge gap between the text field text and the text field label(line in red).  take a look at the third text field where the gap is minimal.  how to remove the gap so that my label text appeared as the third text field?

I am using the reactive form but it looks like it is much similar to the default flutter text field.
here is partial code

```
Widget amountField() {
    return ReactiveTextField<String>(
      textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
      formControlName: incomeAmountLabel,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: incomeAmountLabel,
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money, color:green),
        labelStyle: TextStyle(height:1, fontSize: text_size_18),
      ),
      validationMessages: (errors) => {
        ValidationMessage.required: 'Name must not be empty',
      },
    );
  }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use **contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),**

It will solve your problem, I was facing same problem. You can change horizontal value according to your choice.